# Override Swagger generated schema definition

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-3.0

How can I override Swagger generated schema definition with a config file?
To have a similar to adding @Schema to class.
I am documenting a Java Spring project.

```
 Version {
     String Name;
     Int version;
    //Getters and setters
    }
```

Example of swagger-override.yaml containing something like:
ComposedData:
type: string
example ="test-10"